# Creating 20 UIViews on different positions without overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

sorry, my english is not so good.
I try to create 20 UIViews with a fix height and width but different positions on the screen.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    view.tag = i;

    randomX = fmod(arc4random(),((int)self.view.frame.size.width - view.frame.size.width));
    randomY = fmod(arc4random(),((int)self.view.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height));
    view.frame = CGRectMake(randomX, randomY, 100, 100);
```

This is only a part of my program.
If i do it like this, the uiviews are created on the screen, but they overlap.
I know there is a function like `CGRectIntersectRect` but i don´t know how it works correctly in this context.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small snippet of code, not really tested, but I think it'll work (I suppose in theory it could run forever, but in reality it takes a split second :-) ) -

```
NSMutableArray *views = [NSMutableArray array];
for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    view.tag = i;

    __block BOOL ok = YES;

    do
    {
        CGFloat randomX = fmod(arc4random(),((int)self.view.frame.size.width - view.frame.size.width));
        CGFloat randomY = fmod(arc4random(),((int)self.view.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height));

        view.frame = CGRectMake(randomX, randomY, 100, 100);

        [views enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
         {
             CGRect rect1 = ((UIView *)obj).frame;
             CGRect rect2 = view.frame;

             if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2))
             {
                 ok = NO;
                 *stop = YES;
             }
             else
                 ok = YES;
         }];
    }
    while (!ok);

    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [views addObject:view];
}
```

Comment: what is a need to manage array of views if view can be reused from main view's subviews array using view tag

Comment: @Ankit - agreed, if there are no other subviews. This method has no significant overhead anyway